# Windows Service DbContext passing - Performance Issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've a windows service that receives data from different GPS devices(30 devices at the moment). As soon as the service receives data from one of the device, it makes a new thread and starts performing checks on the data and finally stores the received data in Database. Now I've different methods for different checks on data and I pass the same context object to them. For Example, the below method is called per new thread.

```
ParentMethod(string receivedData) // Called when I have data from device
{
    // Do something with received data

    using(MyContext db= new MyContext())
    {
        CheckSpeed(db);    // Checks For speed violation
        CheckGeoFence(db); // Checks for Geo Fence entries
        CheckForCommandsToBeSent(db); // Checks for any commands to be sent to device.
    }
}
```

Intermittently, I see timeout issues in the log of the service. I've following queries, and will be extremely glad if some can assist:

1. Am I doing right by passing context in different methods? Or should I create new in every method.
2. I've 4Gb of RAM on VPS where DB(MSSQL Enterprise 2014) and Service is hosted. Is that enough for handling around 500 records per minute? Currently service receives 60 records per minute.
3. When I go to Activity monitor in SSMS I see following:[image] I see high lock wait time, is that Ok?
4. In my scenario, is it better to use direct stored procedures then ef linq calls?

Thanks for giving it a glance.

Comment: Are you creating one thread per request or one thread on the first request which handles all requests?

Comment: 1 thread per record received.

Comment: You should change that. One thread which writes to your DB. And a Threadpool which handle incomming data and put it into an Queue for your DB-Write-Thread. There're a couple of issues with one thread per request when many requests at the same time arise, for example context switches. I would also recommend to create new connections per record, I would use a connectionpool here too. High lock time is always bad. :) Because there's something waiting.

Comment: You also just could use a threadpool with one connection per thread which writes to your DB. The more I think about the more I like that instead of one writing thread.

Comment: There's not enough data, but one of reasons for high lock activity can be lack of useful indexes (I mean unique index or better - primary key) so your UPDATEs must scan the whole table instead of just seeking to update one row. Look for it.

Comment: @Endrju The main table has indexes and rarely there are any UPDATE statements in service. Majority are INSERT statements.

Comment: @user743414 I'm using a TCPServer Library that has thread pools. It creates one thread per message. In that thread I run the attached code. I also have SQL Connection Pools(Max.1000). Moreover I think I m creating a new connection by creating a new context in every thread.

Comment: INSERT Statements also lock the Index, because with every INSERT the index has to be updated. That brings me back to my one and only writing thread. :D When the inserts are causing the locks then it could be better to do bulk inserts. But then you can't use your one connection per thread approach. What are doing CheckSpeed and CheckGeoFence? Are they inserting data or just reading data? You could try dirty reads on them, if they just read data.

Comment: @user743414 Yes, it may work the way you are telling me. But for that I need to do sizable modifications.Is there something wrong in my approach? And If it needs to Lock the index during insert. Insert should not take any time, cause its just simple insert. That should not cause other operations to wait for long or cause timeouts.

Comment: Wrong? Not in general.